# Background of DIV needs to change when click on it

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I do the following:

I have several DIVS

```
<div style="background-color: black;">text1</div>
<div style="background-color: black;">text2</div>
<div style="background-color: black;">text3</div>
<div style="background-color: black;">text4</div>
<div style="background-color: black;">text5</div>
<div style="background-color: black;">text6</div>
```

When someone is clicking on the DIV with text5, the background colour needs to change to RED.
When that same person is clicking on DIV with text 3, the background colour of text5 need to go back to black en text3 should get the background color to RED. And so on with the other DIVS.

So the background colour needs to change when someone is cliking on another DIV.

Is this possible with a simple javascript?

Comment: have you tried to use tabindex and focus pseudoclass ?

Comment: You should try to code at least. But it's possible with a simple javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add classes to the divs in html so that you're able to access them from the javascript along with an `onclick` so that you can detect when each div has been clicked. From the `onclick` call a javascript function passing in the current div as a parameter using `this`.

In the `changeColour` function (that's getting called from the `onclick`) in javascript first call a function to set all the divs back to the default colour by getting an array of them all using the `document.getElementsByClassName`, loop through them and reset the colour.

Once that's done and the code executeion is back in the `changeColour` function change the colour of the clicked on div (which was passed in as a parameter).

```js
function changeColour(item)
{
    resetColour();
    item.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}

function resetColour()
{
    var divsToReset = document.getElementsByClassName("colouredDivs");
    for(var i=0; i < divsToReset.length; i++) 
    {
         var div = divsToReset[i];
         div.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="colouredDivs" style="background-color: black;" onClick="changeColour(this);">text1</div>
<div class="colouredDivs"  style="background-color: black;" onClick="changeColour(this);">text2</div>
<div class="colouredDivs"  style="background-color: black;" onClick="changeColour(this);">text3</div>
<div class="colouredDivs"  style="background-color: black;" onClick="changeColour(this);">text4</div>
<div class="colouredDivs"  style="background-color: black;" onClick="changeColour(this);">text5</div>
<div class="colouredDivs"  style="background-color: black;" onClick="changeColour(this);">text6</div>
```

Comment: I agree with the approach of using a class to assign the background color but, in this case, it would make sense to delegate the styling too to classes (after all, that is the primary purpose of a CSS class), rather than using them just as selectors. You can see an example of what I mean here: https://jsfiddle.net/1rujyth9/1/

Comment: @secan I agree. That's a much more elegant way to do it and fits the separation of style, display and function nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `forEach()` and `for`.

**Without** declaring **events javascript** in the **html** structure.

```js
let div = document.querySelectorAll('div');

div.forEach(function(div_current) {
  div_current.addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
      div[i].style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    }
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  });
});
```

```html
<div style="background-color: black;">text1</div>
<div style="background-color: black;">text2</div>
<div style="background-color: black;">text3</div>
<div style="background-color: black;">text4</div>
<div style="background-color: black;">text5</div>
<div style="background-color: black;">text6</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to give your tags a propper class.
Then you can add an event to these elements to react as you want.

```js
let tags = document.getElementsByClassName('color-tag');
for (let item of document.getElementsByClassName('color-tag')) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function () {
        for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
            tags[i].style.backgroundColor = 'black';
        }
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="color-tag" style="background-color: black;">text1</div>
<div class="color-tag" style="background-color: black;">text2</div>
<div class="color-tag" style="background-color: black;">text3</div>
<div class="color-tag" style="background-color: black;">text4</div>
<div class="color-tag" style="background-color: black;">text5</div>
<div class="color-tag" style="background-color: black;">text6</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A parent element would make this easier and allow you to isolate the components.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper').forEach(wrap => {
  wrap.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => {
      div.classList.remove('selected');
    });

    e.target.classList.add('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  color: #FFF;
}

.selected {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div style="background-color: black;">text1</div>
  <div style="background-color: black;">text2</div>
  <div style="background-color: black;">text3</div>
  <div style="background-color: black;">text4</div>
  <div style="background-color: black;">text5</div>
  <div style="background-color: black;">text6</div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div style="background-color: black;">text1</div>
  <div style="background-color: black;">text2</div>
  <div style="background-color: black;">text3</div>
  <div style="background-color: black;">text4</div>
  <div style="background-color: black;">text5</div>
  <div style="background-color: black;">text6</div>
</div>
```

An alternative, without JavaScript, could be to use `tabIndex` in conjunction with the `:focus` pseudo-class selector.

```css
body {
  color: #FFF;
}

.wrapper div:focus {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div style="background-color: black;" tabIndex="1">text1</div>
  <div style="background-color: black;" tabIndex="1">text2</div>
  <div style="background-color: black;" tabIndex="1">text3</div>
  <div style="background-color: black;" tabIndex="1">text4</div>
  <div style="background-color: black;" tabIndex="1">text5</div>
  <div style="background-color: black;" tabIndex="1">text6</div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div style="background-color: black;" tabIndex="1">text1</div>
  <div style="background-color: black;" tabIndex="1">text2</div>
  <div style="background-color: black;" tabIndex="1">text3</div>
  <div style="background-color: black;" tabIndex="1">text4</div>
  <div style="background-color: black;" tabIndex="1">text5</div>
  <div style="background-color: black;" tabIndex="1">text6</div>
</div>
```